# Objective-C (IOS 6.1+): Draw Text in a shape or path

Tags: ios, objective-c, word-wrap

I was wondering if there is an "easy" way to draw text in a shape or a view or a path so that the characters wrap if the text line is too long (even with fonts with different sizes).

Below just an picture to describe the idea...

How can i check that a particular character size goes beyond the shape border and therefore the characters should be wrapped?

Any help on this...highly appreciated... :-)
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this on iOS. (At least Apple doesn't provide a way).

You will have to do it yourself - create a `CGPathRef` of your shape. Then use `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox` and `CGPathContainsPoint` to determine where to wrap your text. You can find out the size required for a string using `-[NSString sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]`.